# Sourcetree Custom Actions - Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8

Tags: macos, mac, git, sourcetree

I am attempting to use Sourcetree Custom Actions to run a shell script:

[image: SourceTree Custom Actions]

When I press the hotkey, I instead get the error:

> hubSync.sh
>   Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8
>   Completed with errors, see above

Why is Sourcetree not running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed by adding an [interpreter to the first line of your script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967902/why-do-you-need-to-put-bin-bash-at-the-beginning-of-a-script-file):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It appears that Sourcetree is not setting a default interpreter for the NSTask they are using to launch the script:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559608/running-shell-script-with-nstask-causes-posix-spawn-error

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the following to the beginning of the .sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1
```

Then in the Sourcetree Custom Action Parameters, add this parameter:

```
$REPO
```

This way the .sh script will receive $REPO (the repo path) as the $1 parameter, and cd will go to this dir before running commands.

Here's another example showing how to do it: https://gist.github.com/mike3k/6125852

Answer (score 0):

For me it was changing the interpreter to zsh like so:

`#!/bin/zsh`